# undefined reference to ndk boost android

Tags: android, c++, boost, android-ndk

I have a problem when creating an executable with ndk using the BOOST libraries in c ++ using already mentioned ndk, this is the problem

```
C:\Users\GENERAL\Downloads\Compressed\tcpproxy\proxy\jni>ndk-build
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: proxy <= tcpproxy_server.cpp
[armeabi] Executable     : proxy
C:/Users/GENERAL/Downloads/Compressed/tcpproxy/proxy//jni/boost_1_56_0/boost/sys
tem/error_code.hpp:322: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_cat
egory()'
C:/Users/GENERAL/Downloads/Compressed/tcpproxy/proxy//jni/boost_1_56_0/boost/thr
ead/exceptions.hpp:51: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_cate
gory()'
C:/Users/GENERAL/Downloads/Compressed/tcpproxy/proxy//jni/boost_1_56_0/boost/asi
o/error.hpp:225: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_category()
'
C:/Users/GENERAL/Downloads/Compressed/tcpproxy/proxy//jni/boost_1_56_0/boost/asi
o/error.hpp:225: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_category()
'
C:/Users/GENERAL/Downloads/Compressed/tcpproxy/proxy//jni/boost_1_56_0/boost/sys
tem/error_code.hpp:221: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_ca
tegory()'
C:/Users/GENERAL/Downloads/Compressed/tcpproxy/proxy//jni/boost_1_56_0/boost/sys
tem/error_code.hpp:222: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_ca
tegory()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [C:/Users/GENERAL/Downloads/Compressed/tcpproxy/proxy//obj/local/a
rmeabi/proxy] Error 1
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES       += $(LOCAL_PATH)/boost_1_56_0 #patch of include BOOST
LOCAL_MODULE    := proxy
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := tcpproxy_server.cpp
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_CFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_STL := gnustl_static
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11
```

that is the error that I get when compiling. already investigate but can not find the solution so please thank your answer to be able to repair it and because generating that error thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the *boost_system* library. You can add *-lboost_system* to your linker flags to find related library symbols in Android.mk (Assuming that boost is built as static):

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES = -lboost_system ...
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```